# glew header file in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I've installed glew. I'm using sample code just to see an example of a program using OpenGL. To compile the program the sample code instructs me to compile with this extension

```
-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -lGLEW
```

If I don't use this extension the header file is not found.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

Do I have to use extensions like this all the time? Why can't the header be found without this extension? What if I just put the `/opt/local/include` and `/opt/local/lib` in my `PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-I` option means "include this directory in the **header search paths list**". If you don't add `-I/opt/local/include` you won't be able to include the files inside this directory. You gotta do it all the time. There's no problem on doing this... it's free! Add to PATH is not enough.